# From typelist to argument pack

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, typelist

I have a typelist of the form described here:

http://www.drdobbs.com/generic-programmingtypelists-and-applica/184403813

Each type has a duck-typed function (template/compile-time virtual) called `get()` which returns a **simple type** like this:

```
struct Float {
  float get() { return 7.0; }
};
struct Int {
  int get() { return 7; }
};
typedef typelist<Float, typelist<Int, null_typelist>> types;
```

I also have a function that takes a variadic number of **simple type** arguments, like this:

```
template<typename... Args>
foo(Args... args)
{
}
```

Now I need a way to call `foo` given `types`. I think there's a solution to this, via a tuple, but I'm really far from a solution that works...
I hope you can help me here!

Comment: Why are you using C++03 typelists in C++11?!

Comment: The typelist in question is "returned" by a class before it is constructed. Is there a better way to do that in c++11?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do: types is a type (such as int) and you want to call a function that expects instances of some types (such as 7). If you have some kind of tuple-like object then it should be possible to do what you want.

Comment: `template<class...>struct types{using type=types;};` is a C++11 style type list. (`using type=types;` optional)

Comment: @Yakk, this could be useful. What would the typelist then look like for my example where it contains an `F` and an `I`?

Comment: It would be `types<F,I>`, instead of `type_list< F, type_list< I, null_typelist >>`.

Comment: Can you give me a link to a more elaborate example, please? I can't seem to get it to do anything useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code converts `typelist` to `tuple` and calls `foo` with simple types.

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

template<typename H, typename T>
struct typelist
{
    typedef H Head;
    typedef T Tail;
};

struct null_typelist {};


template<int... Indices>
struct indices {
    using next = indices<Indices..., sizeof...(Indices)>;
};

template<int Size>
struct build_indices {
    using type = typename build_indices<Size - 1>::type::next;
};

template<>
struct build_indices<0> {
    using type = indices<>;
};

template<typename T>
using Bare = typename std::remove_cv<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>::type;

template<typename Tuple>
constexpr
typename build_indices<std::tuple_size<Bare<Tuple>>::value>::type
make_indices()
{ return {}; }

template<typename T, typename... Args>
struct tuple_push;

template<typename T, typename... Args>
struct tuple_push<T, std::tuple<Args...>>
{
    typedef std::tuple<Args..., T> type;
};

template<typename TL>
struct typelist_to_tuple;

template<typename H, typename T>
struct typelist_to_tuple<typelist<H, T>>
{
    typedef typename tuple_push<H, typename typelist_to_tuple<T>::type>::type type;
};

template<typename H>
struct typelist_to_tuple<typelist<H, null_typelist>>
{
    typedef std::tuple<H> type;
};

struct Float {
  float get() const { return 7.5; }
};
struct Int {
  int get() const { return 7; }
};

template<typename... Args>
void foo(const Args&... args)
{
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
void foo(const T& current, const Args&... args)
{
    std::cout << current << std::endl;
    foo(args...);
}

template<typename Tuple, int... Indices>
void apply(const Tuple& tuple, indices<Indices...>)
{
    foo(std::get<Indices>(tuple).get()...);
}

template<typename Tuple>
void apply(const Tuple& tuple)
{
    apply(tuple, make_indices<Tuple>());
}

int main()
{
    typedef typelist<Int, typelist<Float, typelist<Int, null_typelist>>> list;
    typedef typelist_to_tuple<list>::type tuple;
    tuple t = std::make_tuple(Int(), Float(), Int());
    apply(t);
}
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1796fa420cc271f4)

Comment: How does build_indices work? And what is sizeof...(Indices) for?

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be done without using `std::tuple`. As others have mentioned, C++11 and onwards support typelists based on parameter packs, which are much easier to work with than the C++03 recursive typelists:

```cpp
template <typename...>
struct tlist {};
```

Assuming the C++03 typelists are part of an API that you can't change, the first thing is to convert the C++03 typelist to a C++11 typelist. That can be done with some empty function declarations acting as type functions:

```cpp
// Concatenate two tlist types
template <typename... Ts, typename... Us>
static auto concat_impl(tlist<Ts...>, tlist<Us...>) -> tlist<Ts..., Us...>;

// Base case
static auto to_tlist_impl(null_typelist) -> tlist<>;

// Recursive case
template <typename Head, typename Tail>
static auto to_tlist_impl(typelist<Head, Tail>)
    -> decltype(concat_impl(tlist<Head>{}, to_tlist_impl(Tail{})));

// Alias template to make usage easier
template <typename Typelist>
using to_tlist = decltype(to_tlist_impl(Typelist{}));
```

Next, provide a helper function to take the parameter pack out of a `tlist` and pass it to the `foo` function. The original question did not specify how the types should be constructed, so here they are just default constructed as they are passed in to `foo`.

```cpp
template <typename... Ts>
void call_foo(tlist<Ts...>) {
    foo(Ts{}...);
}
```

Finally, to call `foo` with a recursive `typelist` type just convert it to a `tlist` with the `to_tlist` type function:

```cpp
    using list = typelist<Int, typelist<Float, typelist<String, null_typelist>>>;
    call_foo(to_tlist<list>{});
```

Godbolt example: https://godbolt.org/z/j8P55v7Kb